# how to build a modular website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I just joined a small website development team and the project we are working on right now is a shopping website. The framework we use is codeigniter. I'm the only newbie in the team. Other people in the team have worked together for a while. They want to make the functions of the website modular, which means they want to avoid repeated code and each of us is responsible for certain parts and after we finish our own part we can put them together. But I realize that they haven't even discussed about what standard we should follow, like the style of the website, the layout, and what to do if we want to make the website modular, etc. I wanna talk to the head of the team about this and I'm actually willing to do the job if necessary, but I don't know much about the procedures of website development, especially that of how to make the website modular. Can someone teach me a little bit about that? or some recommendations? online resources? books? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at the architecture and design decisions of major [content management systems](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-Management-System). Personally I find the design of [Drupal](http://drupal.org) a powerful modular design (although it might seem at first glance very complex).

Here is a [nice overview](http://drupal.org/getting-started/before/overview) about the architecture of Drupal as a starting point. Good luck